Sci-fi series with young adults on a planet
I'm looking for a sci-fi series with young adults who wake up with no memory. It's not Dark Matter or Deepwater Black (Mission Genesis).
I think they are on a planet with their ship. One character is a female android. When they start getting their memories back, a few people blame the android. For a few episodes, there are two groups formed; one that is on the android's side and one that wants it destroyed. There are also floating orb androids which can talk and perform different tasks. There are three flying orbs; a red one, a blue one, and a green or maybe yellow one. Towards the end of the series, the two groups join as one again because they want to get somewhere and because of a foreign space being threat.
I don't know when it was made or by whom. I saw it on YouTube in 2018, then it was deleted. I also remember that the people spoke English, but there were French or Dutch subtitles.

There are (at least) two shows with the title Dark Matter; one from this year and the other from 2015-2017. Are you certain that the show you're looking for is neither of these? Because the plot summary for the earlier show sounds extremely similar to what you've described, and the release date is a good fit too.

Despite your protestations to the contrary, could this be Dark Matter (2015)? - "In the dystopian 27th century, six people wake up on a deserted spaceship with no memory of who they are or what they're doing there. They reluctantly team up and set off to find answers with the help of a female android."

I watched Dark Matter; the central premise of six people waking with no memory matches, but I don't recall floating orbs. There are no shortage of disagreements but not two separate factions. Could be misremembered details but equally could be a different series.

It is absolutely not either Dark Matter. This is why I'm here posting the question. Dark Matter is similar to many others in that they travel to different planets. The show I'm looking for has the people on one planet the entire time. I don't know when it aired. I saw it on YouTube in 2018. I thought it might be a clue that it was in English, but whomever posted on YouTube uploaded the show with a Latin based language as subtitles. I remember thinking it was French. Also, the orbs are important. As the show progresses they find each one has special tech properties.

@GaryMartinez - You need to add those details into the question :-)

@Valorum read the original post. The same relevant info is there. People want to assume and jump to conclusions. If someone doesn't know, then don't post. The original post clearly says that it is not Dark Matter or Mission Genesis. If someone doesn't know a show that fits the criteria, then don't post a reply.

I read it, and my comment seems to have resulted in you recalling additional details ("As the show progresses they find each one has special tech properties.") that weren't in the original post
